# arabic support logcat error

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-logcat

![i develop an application which support Arabic language the problem is that when i run my application it gives an error"Arabic font unexpectedly stopped working forced closed"please help me in detecting error .i posted both log n source code file][1]

```
package com.android.arabicfont;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    AssetManager arabi_font;
    TextView tx;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"dejavusans.ttf");
        tx.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshape("\u0641\u0641\u0633"));
        TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tx.setTypeface(face);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    }
```

Comment: 1.Where is your mentioned logcat? 2.what is `ArabicUtilities`? 3.Where have you put your arabic font?

Comment: i made another activity for arabic utility and i placed my ttf font file in asset

Comment: No one will be able to help without logcat, I guess

Comment: i have found the solution thanx every one for help